# Last element doesn't work well in a Doubly Linked List implementation in C

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

here is all dependency needed in this part of code:

```
#define NTRANCHES 1024

size_t nb_blocs(size_t n){
    return ceil((double)n/(double)sizeof(align_data));
}

typedef union {
    intmax_t a;
    void* adr;
    long double c;
} align_data;

typedef struct node{
    ptrdiff_t next; //shift from the start point of memory
    ptrdiff_t previous; //same like next
    size_t len;
    align_data data[];
} node;

//tranche mean cut in french!
 typedef struct{
    ptrdiff_t decalage; //the shift from the start point of the memory
    size_t nb_blocs; // number of blocs in this cut
} tranche; //used to save free space of the memory in another array called libre* in the head

typedef struct{
    void* memory; //single memory to save all nodes
    ptrdiff_t first; //shift from start
    ptrdiff_t last;  //shift from start
    tranche* libre; //array to save free spaces
    size_t size;    //size of the memory
    size_t nb_elem; //number of elements in the memory
    size_t nb_bloc_libre; //number of free blocs
} head;

void* ld_create(size_t nboctets){
    tranche* tab_tranches =malloc(NTRANCHES * sizeof(tranche));
    head* res=malloc(sizeof(head));
    res->size=nb_blocs(nboctets)*sizeof(align_data);
    res->memory=malloc(res->size);
    res->first=0;
    res->last=0;
    res->libre=tab_tranches;
    res->nb_bloc_libre=nb_blocs(nboctets);
    res->nb_elem=0;
    tab_tranches[0].decalage=0;
    tab_tranches[0].nb_blocs=res->nb_bloc_libre;
    return res;

} //to initialize the memory

 void* ld_first(void* liste){
     head* head=liste;
     if(head->nb_elem==0){
         return NULL;
     }
     return (node*)(align_data*)(head->memory + head->first);
 }

 void* ld_last(void* liste){
    head* head=liste;
    if(head->nb_elem==0){
         return NULL;
    }
    return (node*)(align_data*)(head->memory + head->last);
 }
```

and here is the function that doesn't work well:

```
void* ld_insert_first(void* liste, size_t len, void* p_data){
    // len : length of the whole node
    head* hd=liste;
    node* new_node;
    node* first_node = ld_first(hd);

    tranche* tab_tranche = hd->libre; //to maintain free spaces in the memory

    for(int i=0;i<NTRANCHES;i++){
        if( tab_tranche[i].nb_blocs> nb_blocs(len)){
            int dec=tab_tranche[i].decalage;
            printf("dec: %d\n",dec);
            new_node = (node*)(align_data*)(hd->memory+dec); 

            new_node->previous=0;
            new_node->next= hd->first - dec;
            new_node->len=len;
            memmove(new_node->data , (align_data*) p_data , len-sizeof(node));

            if(first_node!=NULL)
                first_node->previous = dec - hd->first;

            hd->first = dec;

            if(hd->nb_elem==0){
                hd->last= dec;
            }
            tab_tranche[i].decalage = dec + nb_blocs(len);
            tab_tranche[i].nb_blocs -= nb_blocs(len);

            hd->nb_elem++;
            hd->nb_bloc_libre--;

            break;

        }
    }
    return new_node;
}
```

and here is a test that doesn't work well.
when I insert just one element at the first of the list, the last element is correct; but if I insert 2 or more elements, the last element will be a large random number!
We can see that `head->last` will always be `0` after the first insertion so I can't understand why the function doesn't print the correct number after the first insertion:

```
int main(){

    head* hd= ld_create(1000);
    align_data data1[5];
    data1->a=1;
    (data1+1)->a=2;
    (data1+2)->a=3;
    (data1+3)->a=4;
    (data1+4)->a=5;

    align_data data2[3];
    data2->a=10;
    (data2+1)->a=20;
    (data2+2)->a=30;

    ld_insert_first(hd,sizeof(node)+sizeof(data1),data1);
    printf("%ld \n", ((node*) ld_last(hd)) -> len); //print 112 correct!

    ld_insert_first(hd,sizeof(node)+sizeof(data2),data2);
    printf("%ld \n", ((node*) ld_last(hd)) -> len); //print a large number!

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is a standard case where using a debugger you can find the error easily...

Comment: I just print `hd->last` every time and it is `0`  so `ld_last` should be always the first element in memory! I don't understand why it changes after the first insertion.
If I use debugger I can just know this kind of things.

Comment: There is not enough information to reproduce the problem. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I edited my code now you have really all the things that is needed!

Comment: Can you post the whole main function so the code is reproducible?

Comment: @teowey ok now i have edited the code so you can compile and run it.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @EdwinAnsari Please paste the headers you use.

Comment: @teowey i pasted all of the variable and struct of my header in the first section.